# Smart Lock for Passwords with Gigya Android SDK

Tags: android, gigya, google-smartlockpasswords

Does [Gigya Android SDK v4](https://developers.gigya.com/display/GD/Android+SDK+v4) provide the possibility to enable saving passwords in [Smart Lock for Passwords](https://developers.google.com/identity/smartlock-passwords/android/overview) ?

I am using the [WebBridge](https://developers.gigya.com/display/GD/Android+SDK+v4#AndroidSDKv4-UsingtheGigyaWebBridgeexplicitly.) implementation of the SDK to login my users, and I need to enable this functionality into my app.

I can successfully implement the **get** password from Smart Lock. But since I am using the web bridge to login my users, I can't **save** the user credentials to Smart Lock, as I can't retrieve the user password from the Gigya SDK upon login.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are providing a GigyaPluginCallback to you WebBridge component onAttach method.
You can use the "onFieldChange" to determine the value inputed to the screenset and manage the the credentials.